# Is there a way to force Google Maps to show Traffic by default?

Tags: google-maps

When I hit up maps.google.com, it goes to my default map.  Is there way to force it to show me traffic so that I don't have to hit the Traffic button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this link instead:

**http://maps.google.com/maps?layer=t**

The trick is in the `?layer=t` query string ;)

Comment: This link will also work on the mobile website (and you can set it as a bookmark on your home screen to avoid typing it every time).